# How can I split an alphanumeric string in excel at each letter and capture the position of that letter

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to split an alphanumeric string into parts based on the letters in the string. There will always be one or two numbers followed by a letter.  For example, '5F18J21H', I would like to know that letter 1 is F and is in position 2, letter 2 is J and in position 5, letter 3 is H and in position 8.  Can this be done with a function, or is vba the only option?  Any **help** is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give some more examples, and what your desired output is? Do you just want to know the character position of each letter in a string?

Comment: so what would your output look like?  would it be in multiple cells as a small table, or one cell?

Comment: @Jeeped - Thanks for the feedback! I edited the question to try and meet your standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a small table, let's get the location first:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN($A$1)))/(ISERROR(--MID($A$1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN($A$1))),1))),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

And copy down.

This will return the location of all the letters.

[image]

From this a simple MID will get the letter:

```
=IF(B1<>"",MID($A$1,B1,1),"")
```

[image]